# PHP preg_replace surrounded by pipes?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I have just come across a regular expression in the WordPress core which intrigues me...
I have found regular expressions like this before and wondered about them, but they have worked so I have not altered them. The pieces of which I am interested in are as follows:

`|(?<!%)%f|` and `|(?<!%)(%s)|` - notice how they are surrounded by pipes rather than a forward slash?

I have done some searching and can not find out what this changes in the expression?? I know that in an expression themselves they are almost like an `or` - I get that. But in place of the forward slash?

Could someone please explain what is happening here?
One of my only thoughts is something along the following lines...

`|(?<!%)` means either nothing, or the look-forward.

`(%s)|` means either `(%s)` or nothing...

This would be typical of the pipes. However as I said, I have seen it before in place of the forward-slashes, so I am not sure whether this is some un-documented feature of PCRE or something like that?

**EDIT**

If you have the pipes, you do not require the forward slashes. If you do not have the pipes, you get a regex syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just different delimiters for `PCRE` style `REGEX`... I use exclamation points myself.

The pipes are the delimiters, whereas what you're accustomed to are slashes.

`!^[A-Z]+$!i` - all alpha characters case insensitive.

More about delimiters here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Note they use `#` characters in their examples and `%` signs.

Comment: So essentially there is no difference, just for code readability?

Comment: Right. It's just a user preference. Some things are harder to use than others, and it depends on the pattern... I try to find characters that don't come up in my patterns.

Answer (score 0):

It's happen nothing, pipes can be used as delimiters around a pattern in place of `/` like `~`, `#`, `@`, ...